# Unable to understand sync

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Hey I am trying to make 10 threads in a synchronized manner and I came up with the code below however I am not able to understand a part of it as mentioned below. I am still really new to java, I tried looking up synchronized threading from 
[Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java)  but still I am clueless.

```
class question3 {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            data di = new data();
            System.out.println(di.count);

        }
    }
}

class item {
    static int count = 0;
}

class data extends item implements Runnable {
    item d = this;
    Thread t;

    data() {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        d = syn.increment(d);
    }
}

class syn {
    synchronized static item increment(item i) {
        i.count++;
        return (i);
    }

}
```

I am not sure what this part of code does?

```
public void run() {
        d = syn.increment(d);
    }
}

class syn {
    synchronized static item increment(item i) {
        i.count++;
        return (i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: "*I came up with the code*" - "*I am not sure what this part of code does*" - By this, you mean "I copied the code", right? Best ask the author what it does. Another good place for information is the [official Oracle Lesson on Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). But honestly, if you are new to java, start with the [basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). A remark on your code: class names should always start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Turing85 I understand what's happening, but what i don't get is why pass object d and how does di.count works?

Comment: This has nothing to do with synchronization. `di.count` accesses field `count` of instance `di` (which is of type `data`, which inherits from `item`). As I said before: start with the basics.

Comment: that's not what i am asking I am trying to understand why it takes `d=syn.increment(d)` ,

Comment: "*[...] and how does di.count works?*" - "*that's not what i am asking*" - You were not... hm.... To your other question: I don't know why the program was designed as it was. I do not understand it either and would desing it in another way. Again, as I said before: ask the author.

Answer (score 0):

the `run` function is used when starting the thread, this is a must function you need to override when implement `Runnable`. When calling `Thread.start()`, the `run` function will be called.

The `class syn` contains a synchronized method, it is simply mean that only one thread can access it each time, thus make the `incerment` function thread safe.

object `d` has a static variable `count` meaning all instances of `item` class (and `data` ) share the same `count`, so all threads increment the same variable

the line `d = syn.increment(d);` is basically `count++` but in a thread safe way

Comment: I understand what's happening, but what i don't get is why pass object d and how does di.count works?